# GNOME PPP doesn't connect

Tags: modem, ppp

I am a new ubuntu user and connect to the internet using wi-fi broadband on my notebook. But I need to setup a dial-up connection through my phone which can keep me online while I travel.

I have tried connecting to dial-up using pppconfig, wvdial and gnome-ppp. I do not know whether they use the same files for connecting but I have only been able to connect using Gnome-ppp. But the connection is intermittent and disconnects every five seconds or so. The exit code is 16 which I checked in man and got to know that the modem hangs itself up.

I am connecting my phone to ubuntu as a usb modem. And as I am new I might have skipped a step or two.

Please suggest a solution or an alternative to this. I have put down the Gnome-ppp log.

Thanks.

```
--> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.61
--> Cannot get information for serial port.
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: ATZ
ATZ
OK
--> Modem initialized.
--> Sending: ATM1L3DT*99***1#
--> Waiting for carrier.
ATM1L3DT*99***1#
CONNECT
--> Carrier detected. Waiting for prompt.
~[7f]}#@!}!}$} }=}!}$}%\}"}&} } } } }#}%B#}%}%}&}*urW}'}"}(}"mX~
--> PPP negotiation detected.
--> Starting pppd at Sat Apr 28 21:55:55 2012
--> Warning: Could not modify /etc/ppp/chap-secrets: Permission denied
--> --> CHAP (Challenge Handshake) may be flaky.
--> Pid of pppd: 2459
--> Using interface ppp0
--> pppd: xu!
--> pppd: xu!
--> pppd: xu!
--> pppd: xu!
--> pppd: xu!
--> pppd: xu!
--> pppd: xu!
--> pppd: xu!
--> pppd: xu!
--> Disconnecting at Sat Apr 28 21:56:01 2012
--> The PPP daemon has died: A modem hung up the phone (exit code = 16)
--> man pppd explains pppd error codes in more detail.
--> Try again and look into /var/log/messages and the wvdial and pppd man pages for more information.
--> Auto Reconnect will be attempted in 5 seconds
--> Cannot get information for serial port.
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: ATZ
ATZ
OK
--> Modem initialized.
--> Cannot get information for serial port.
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: ATZ
ATZ
OK
--> Modem initialized.
--> Sending: ATM1L3DT*99***1#
--> Waiting for carrier.
ATM1L3DT*99***1#
CONNECT
--> Carrier detected. Waiting for prompt.
~[7f]}#@!}!Q} }=}!}$}%\}"}&} } } } }#}%B#}%}%}&}*u69}'}"}(}"#W~
--> PPP negotiation detected.
--> Starting pppd at Sat Apr 28 21:56:07 2012
--> Warning: Could not modify /etc/ppp/chap-secrets: Permission denied
--> --> CHAP (Challenge Handshake) may be flaky.
--> Pid of pppd: 2470
--> Using interface ppp0
--> pppd: xu!
--> pppd: xu!
--> pppd: xu!
--> pppd: xu!
--> pppd: xu!
--> pppd: xu!
--> pppd: xu!
--> pppd: xu!
--> pppd: xu!
--> Disconnecting at Sat Apr 28 21:56:09 2012
--> The PPP daemon has died: A modem hung up the phone (exit code = 16)
--> man pppd explains pppd error codes in more detail.
--> Try again and look into /var/log/messages and the wvdial and pppd man pages for more information.
--> Auto Reconnect will be attempted in 10 seconds
--> Cannot get information for serial port.
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: ATZ
ATZ
OK
--> Modem initialized.
--> Cannot get information for serial port.
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: ATZ
ATZ
OK
--> Modem initialized.
--> Sending: ATM1L3DT*99***1#
--> Waiting for carrier.
ATM1L3DT*99***1#
CONNECT
--> Carrier detected. Waiting for prompt.
~[7f]}#@!}!@} }=}!}$}%\}"}&} } } } }#}%B#}%}%}&}*uvM}'}"}(}"p}$~
--> PPP negotiation detected.
--> Starting pppd at Sat Apr 28 21:56:20 2012
--> Warning: Could not modify /etc/ppp/chap-secrets: Permission denied
--> --> CHAP (Challenge Handshake) may be flaky.
--> Pid of pppd: 2481
--> Using interface ppp0
--> pppd: xu!
--> pppd: xu!
--> pppd: xu!
--> pppd: xu!
--> pppd: xu!
--> pppd: xu!
--> pppd: xu!
--> pppd: xu!
--> pppd: xu!
--> Disconnecting at Sat Apr 28 21:56:25 2012
--> The PPP daemon has died: A modem hung up the phone (exit code = 16)
--> man pppd explains pppd error codes in more detail.
--> Try again and look into /var/log/messages and the wvdial and pppd man pages for more information.
--> Auto Reconnect will be attempted in 20 seconds
--> Cannot get information for serial port.
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: ATZ
ATZ
OK
--> Modem initialized.
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my problem by running this from the terminal:

```
sudo chgrp dip /etc/ppp/*secrets
sudo chmod 660 /etc/ppp/*secrets
sudo adduser yourusername dip
sudo adduser yourusername dialout
```

Run `gnome-gppp` setup

Exit `gnome-ppp`

Then edit the file `~/.wvdial.conf`

Change line `Stupid Mode = off` to `Stupid Mode = on`

Run `gnome-ppp` and don't do more setup.

This worked for me on 12.04 and 12.10

Answer (score 0):

Just use `sudo wvdial` instead of `wvdial`.

Comment: Giving programs root access is not a good idea unless absolutely necessary. There may be a workaround.\

Answer (score 0):

I'm having problems with the same error. A customer brought in their Ubuntu laptop. Asked that I update it to 12.04 and asked me to add a USB Modem. All that has been done. Gnome-ppp sees the modem, seems to work. It connects and then a few seconds later it disconnects with the PPPD error 16. I've tried using wvdial, it doesn't work. I tried 'sudo wvdial --config=/root/.wvdial.conf' and it does the same thing as gnome-ppp. If some one knows a way around this it sure would be nice if you shared the information with me.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem by running this from the terminal:

```
sudo vim /etc/ppp/options
```

and I removed some conflicting id's, that i found in `/var/log/messages` like

```
11500
cat connect 
braud
```

Run `gnome-ppp`

This worked for me on 12.04 and 12.10

:)